# What happens if you stay on the monitor the whole time?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys

What happens if you stay on the monitor the whole time in Five Nights at Freddy's?
Do you run out of power, do the animatronics pull the tablet away from your face, or does time just not pass?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: You die.

I tested night 5, and immediately starting looking on the monitor. You see the three animatronics, after a few seconds the view gets disturbed, and when you can look again, one is missing. This happens to all of them eventually.

And then at 78% power(!) Bonnie came and ripped my monitor away and I died. The game just continues when you are watching the monitor. Nothing really special.

I tested night 1 twice (the same thing happens):

- Foxy doesn't come out of it's hole in night one, so he can't disturb you.
- Nothing happens until ~45% (3 AM), then Bonnie disappears (after the "view disturbed" screen), at 39%, Chica disappears too. Sometimes, there are hallucinations with "it's me!" arround that time too.
- Then the power ran out and I hadn't enough time.

It's impossible to beat because you run out of power just after 5 AM, because you use your camera all the time thereby doubling the power usage, so you die no matter what.

If you move your monitor away at <20%, you'll die. That's how Chica and Bonnie work. When you move your monitor away, they attack you.

Comment: What do you mean by <20%? So when the power lowers down to <20% you have to close all doors, and look at the monitor the whole time?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I mean that if you'll move the camera away, it's very very likely that you will be killed.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this on night five, and it was very strange! Nothing happened for the longest time, and then I started to hear a sort of moaning/cooing sound, quite high pitched, and it almost sounded like it was saying "hello" or "I'm here." It didn't matter what camera I was on, I kept hearing this. Then all of a sudden Chica pulled me away from the monitor and killed me. I don't know whether this is just with hind sight, but the sounds I was hearing did sound a bit like a chicken, so it made sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you stay on it the whole time you will run out of power and freddy will make you lose

Answer (score 0):

Both Chika and Bonnie when at your doorway will make a moaning sound so you know they are there and once they are there there is nothing you can do except just pull the monoter down to restart or try to make it to 6AM while staying in cams

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have been looking through "The Freddy Files: Updated Edition" recently and this is what I came up with.

When you run out of power, Freddy will sing the Toreador March through his music box and will soon after kill you. Running out of power can be because you use the monitor for too long, close both doors, etc. If you remain on cameras the whole night, then there is a chance that Bonnie or Chica will stop by your door. A problem here is, if either notice you in the office, they will create a low-pitched moan that can sometimes be easily heard, but can only be heard if you stay on the cameras. If you hear this while on cameras, expect a jumpscare that will be delivered in the shape of a rabbit or chicken. Another thing that can happen, if you keep your eyes only on the cameras, is Foxy will run down the hallway and you can't close the door from the monitor. And thus, Foxy kills you with haste.